# Maven - Error Releasing Code to GitHub (Hangs After Push)

Tags: java, git, maven-2, github, maven-release-plugin

I'm attempting to run the `mvn release:prepare` goal and it's hanging after the push. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

```
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 8 seconds
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 13 23:54:59 PDT 2010
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 55M/294M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\development\taylor\my-app
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\development\taylor\my-app
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git commit --verbose -F C:\Users\TAYLOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-1932347225.commit pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\development\taylor\my-app
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git symbolic-ref HEAD"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\development\taylor\my-app
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push git@github.com:tleese22/my-app.git master:master"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\development\taylor\my-app
>>>> hangs here <<<<
```

Below is the SCM section of my pom.xml:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/tleese22/my-app.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:tleese22/my-app.git</developerConnection>
    <url>http://github.com/tleese22/my-app</url>
</scm>

...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Below is my .git/config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    logallrefupdates = true
    bare = false
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:tleese22/my-app.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    pushurl = git@github.com:tleese22/my-app.git
```

Here's the result of git show origin:

```
$ git remote show origin
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Taylor Leese/.ssh/id_rsa':
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:tleese22/my-app.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:tleese22/my-app.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    gh-pages new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    master   new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)

$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: Are the above URL working from command line ?

Comment: I have this problem too; I think it is stuck waiting for a passphrase.  The problem is limited to Windows since Linux can cache the passphrase.  I can't seem to figure out a way to specify a passphrase for the general scm connections.  (It is clearly documented how to specify them for things like site distribution, but that mechanism leverages an id -- and there isn't an id for the scm tag.)

Comment: I ended up using a key without a passphrase.

Comment: This worked for me:
 open git bash and start ssh-agent:
 `..> eval $(ssh-agent -s)`
 add passphrase of local .ssh:
 `..> ssh-add`
 prepare release:
 `..> mvn release:prepare`
 push generated tag 'myApp-1.0.0' to the remot repo:
 `..> git push origin myApp-1.0.0`
 run release:
 `..> mvn release:perform`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the source of [`git builtin-push.c`](http://repo.or.cz/w/git/mingw.git/blame/5d74b7d56b82f42e3536b515400d03b0de21dec0:/builtin-push.c), that means that somehow, no remote are defined for the local Git repo used by the maven script.

```
    static int do_push(const char *repo, int flags)
    {
        int i, errs;
        struct remote *remote = remote_get(repo);

        const char **url;
        int url_nr;


        if (!remote) {
            if (repo)
                die("bad repository '%s'", repo);
            die("No destination configured to push to.");
        }
```

As illustrated by this [blog post](http://blogs.mikeci.com/2010/01/26/working-with-custom-maven-archetypes-part-2/), the maven config is not the all story.

```
~/foo/mikeci-archetype-springmvc-webapp$ git remote add origin git@github.com:amleggett/mikeci-archetype-springmvc-webapp.git
```

A `remote add` is still required, before specifying the maven scm parameters:

> **Updating the POM**
>
> For Maven to function effectively, you should always ensure that you include project VCS information in your POM file.
>   Now that we’ve added the archetype to a Git repository we can include the appropriate `<scm>` configuration:

```
  <scm>
   <connection>
   scm:git:ssh://github.com/amleggett/${artifactId}.git
   </connection>
   <developerConnection>
   scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/amleggett/${artifactId}.git
   </developerConnection>
   <url>
   http://github.com/amleggett/${artifactId}
   </url>
  </scm>
```

The same blog post adds:

> It’s important to understand the meaning of each of the child elements of `<scm>`.
>
> - The `<connection>` element defines a read-only url and
> - the `<developerConnection>` element a read+write url.
>
> For both of these elements the url must adhere to the following convention:

```
 scm:<scm implementation>:<scm implementation-specific path>
```

> - Finally, the `<url>` element content should point to a browsable location and for me this is the GitHub repository home page. Note that in all cases, I’m using an interpolated value which is my project artifactId.
>
> One handy tip is that you can verify this configuration by using the **`maven-scm-plugin`**.
>   This plugin offers ‘vendor’ independent access to common VCS commands by offering a set of command mappings for the configured VCS. The validate goal should confirm all is well:

```
~/foo/mikeci-archetype-springmvc-webapp$ mvn scm:validate
[INFO] Preparing scm:validate
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [scm:validate {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] connectionUrl scm connection string is valid.
[INFO] project.scm.connection scm connection string is valid.
[INFO] project.scm.developerConnection scm connection string is valid.
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: I think my issues is related more to a possible issue with the maven-release-plugin and git rather than me configuring the <scm> section incorrectly, but not positive.

Comment: @Taylor: I agree. The important point in my answer is the '`git remote add`'. The `<scm>` section of the answer is more here for adding some general informations to the topic.

Comment: What if there are more projects running on the CI server?

Comment: @Brovoker it would be best to ask that question as a new one (this one is 5 years old, and I don't have enough information to answer your comment)

Answer (score 27):

I have run into the same problem and I traced this to the fact that git is requiring a passphrase, but Maven has no way to specify an appropriate passphrase, so the process essentially hangs.  Note that this problem is limited to Windows.

The solution is to run **ssh-agent**.  This can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\`.  After you run it, it outputs some environment variables that you need to set.  For example:

> SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-LhiYjP7924/agent.7924; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
>   SSH_AGENT_PID=2792; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
>   echo Agent pid 2792;

So, you need to place these in your environment:

> `C:\> set SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-LhiYjP7924/agent.7924`
>   `C:\> set SSH_AGENT_PID=2792`

Then, you will need to add a passphrase for your particular key file.  Generally, if you issued a command like `git fetch origin master` for your project, you will get a passphrase prompt like:  `Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Anthony Whitford/.ssh/id_rsa'` -- that is the file that you need to register with the agent.  So, the command is:

> `C:\> ssh-add "/c/Users/Anthony Whitford/.ssh/id_rsa"`

It will prompt you for a passphrase, so enter it.  You should see an `Identity added` message.  Now, the agent knows the passphrase so that you will not be prompted to specify it anymore.

If you have multiple instances of command prompts, make sure that each command prompt has the appropriate SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID environment variables set.  You can validate that this is working by running a command like `ssh -v git@github.com` and if you DO NOT get prompted for a passphrase, it is working!

Note that when you logoff, the ssh-agent will shut down and so when you log back in or restart your computer, you will need to repeat these steps.  My understanding is that your passphrase is stored in memory, not persisted to disk, for security reasons.

Comment: This is actually the best possible answer that also includes workaround for ss-agent issues. You saved me a lot of time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can i use pageant instead? Or is pageant for putty only?

Comment: Pageant should work too as it supports SSH.  http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant

Answer (score 9):

The `mvn release:prepare` goal always runs in non-interactive mode, so you can't enter the ssh passphrase git is waiting for while pushing to the remote repository. 
You can use an SSH agent to manage that, but if this problem only appears during the release process, there is another solution : preparing the release locally, and pushing the tag afterwards.

For this you have to use version 2.1+ of [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html) that comes with the `pushChanges` parameter.

```
mvn -DpushChanges=false release:prepare
```

By the way, your tag is created into your local GIT repository and you can then push it to the remote repository as usual, with a `git push` command.

This method is useful for Eclipse users because Eclipse comes with an embedded ssh-agent but this agent is not used by maven while performing a release:prepare, even when using eGit.

Comment: It may be easier to add <pushChanges>false</pushChanges> in the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 4):

These are the exact sequence of commands I followed to get rid of this error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin>bash

bash-3.1$ eval 'ssh-agent -s'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-ZARFN11804/agent.11804; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=10284; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 10284;

bash-3.1$ exec ssh-agent bash
bash-3.1$ ssh-add "/c/Users/idntus/.ssh/id_rsa"
Enter passphrase for /c/Users/idntus/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /c/Users/idntus/.ssh/id_rsa (/c/Users/idntus/.ssh/id_rsa)

bash-3.1$ mvn release:prepare release:perform
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing which worked for me was specifying GIT user name and password as maven parameters:

```
mvn -Dusername=jenkins -Dpassword=******** release:prepare release:perform
```

To hide password in Jenkins output console I installed and configured Mask Passwords Plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another reason it could hang is if `github.com` isn't in the `known_hosts` file. SSH will therefore hang waiting for the user to accept authenticity of the host.

To add `github.com` to your known hosts just do a quick SSH to it: `ssh github.com`. The SSH client will then ask you to confirm the authenticity of the host. Type "Yes" and it'll say that its permanently added `github.com` to your list of known hosts.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same problem, I had tried many ways but got to resolved it with below steps:

**1. you need check git origin**

**2. update your pom.xml,find scm section,**

```
 change github ssh address the `:` to '/'

  before 

   <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com:xxx/xxxin.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com:xxx/xxxin.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/xxx/jenkins-xxx-plugin</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
   </scm>

then

   <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/xxx/xxxin.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/xxx/xxxin.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/xxx/jenkins-xxx-plugin</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
   </scm>
```

**3. set   ~/.m2/settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
        <id>maven.jenkins-ci.org</id> <!-- For parent 1.397 or newer; before   this use id java.net-m2-repository -->
        <username>your jenkins username</username>
        <password>your jenkins password</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

**4. then commit & push your changes**

**5. run mvn release:prepare release:perform**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
I tried all the above solutions and still it did not work.

That was because I was still doing one thing wrong: for the ssh commands I used git bash while for the maven command I used the command prompt. And there not all the git commands were available.

After adding the complete git bin folder to the PATH variable everything worked for me.