# Jenkins Maven Release:Branch Hangs After Pushing Changes to Gihub

Tags: github, jenkins, hudson, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I am running maven release:branch while building a maven job in Jenkins. And I am having similar issue as mentioned in this question [maven-error-releasing-code-to-github-hangs-after-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243755/maven-error-releasing-code-to-github-hangs-after-push) but with Jenkins.

Here is the console output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-test-2 0.0.6-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.3.1:branch (default-cli) @ maven-test-2 ---
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **\release.properties, **\pom.xml.next, **\pom.xml.releaseBackup, **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.branch, **\pom.xml.tag
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Maven-Test-09-SEP-03-03\workspace
What is the new working copy version for "maven-test-2"? (com.paypal:maven-test-2) 0.0.7-SNAPSHOT: : [INFO] Transforming 'maven-test-2'...
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Maven-Test-09-SEP-03-03\workspace
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Maven-Test-09-SEP-03-03\workspace
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git commit --verbose -F C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\maven-scm-574276238.commit pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Maven-Test-09-SEP-03-03\workspace
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git symbolic-ref HEAD"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Maven-Test-09-SEP-03-03\workspace
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push git@github.paypal.com:XXXXXXXX@github.paypal.com:atagrawal/maven-test-3.git master:master"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Maven-Test-09-SEP-03-03\workspace
----------------------------It Hangs Here------------------------
```

Does any of you have idea how to resolve this if 1). If I am the admin user 2). I am a normal user and doesn't have access to "Manage Jenkins". This is because jenkins is managed by another team and developer can only build jobs.