# Jenkins Release artifact job running on Windows fails in Git push command

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I am building a Jenkins Job on Windows to automate the release process. Hence I am using the Maven release plugin.

When I do a Perform Maven Release on the job, it asks me for the SCM login, SCM Comment Prefix and SCM tag. But the job fails while doing a git push to commit the changes with the following logs.

```
   [INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
   [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
   [INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release      Artifacts
   [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status"
   [INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release  Artifacts
   [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git commit --verbose -F C:\windows\TEMP\maven-scm-1948138390.commit pom.xml"
   [INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
   [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git symbolic-ref HEAD"
   [INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
   [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push   git@github.com:elizabetht/StudentEnrollmentWithREST.git master:master"
   [INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 2:03.980s
   [INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 03 14:29:30 CST 2014
   [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/21M
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release- plugin:2.2.2:prepare (default-cli) on project StudentEnrollmentWithREST: Unable to commit  files
   [ERROR] Provider message:
   [ERROR] The git-push command failed.
   [ERROR] Command output:
   [JENKINS] Archiving C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts\pom.xml to com.github.elizabetht/StudentEnrollmentWithREST/1.3-SNAPSHOT/StudentEnrollmentWithREST-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
   [ERROR] Permission denied (publickey).
   [ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   [ERROR] and the repository exists.
   [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
channel stopped
   Finished: FAILURE
```

I believe this error has to do with running a ssh agent for the Jenkins job. I followed the solution given in the stackoverflow question [Maven - Error Releasing Code to GitHub (Hangs After Push)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243755/maven-error-releasing-code-to-github-hangs-after-push?lq=1) and the git push works fine in a terminal.

The SCM parameters settings in pom.xml are as follows

```
<scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:elizabetht/StudentEnrollmentWithREST.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:elizabetht/StudentEnrollmentWithREST.git</developerConnection>
        <url>http://github.com/elizabetht/StudentEnrollmentWithREST</url>           
    </scm>
```

Output of mvn scm:validate is as follows

```
$ mvn scm:validate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building StudentEnrollmentWithREST 1.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-scm-plugin:1.9:validate (default-cli) @ StudentEnrollmentWithREST >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.2:enforce (enforce-maven) @ StudentEnrollmentWithREST ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-scm-plugin:1.9:validate (default-cli) @ StudentEnrollmentWithREST <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-scm-plugin:1.9:validate (default-cli) @ StudentEnrollmentWithREST ---
[INFO] connectionUrl scm connection string is valid.
[INFO] project.scm.connection scm connection string is valid.
[INFO] project.scm.developerConnection scm connection string is valid.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.325s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 04 18:06:04 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Adding the output of 'ssh -vT git@github.com'

```
C:\Users\Sara>ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.131] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Sara/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Sara/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Sara/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Ope
n-5ubuntu1+github5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5 pat OpenSSH
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Sara/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Sara/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/Sara/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status re
Hi elizabetht! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub doe
ell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 0 bytes in 0.1 se
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 0.0
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Could anyone help with pointers on how to get this running as a Jenkins job on Windows?

Comment: Please share the POM file in which you've configured the SCM settings?

Comment: @Amir Keibi: Added the SCM Parameters in the Edit.

Comment: Thank you. And what's the output of "mvn scm:validate"?

Comment: @AmirKeibi: Added the output in the Edit. The connection urls are valid

Comment: Other issues I can think of are network and DNS issues as well as SSH key problems. Both can be checked using "ssh -vT git@github.com". Please add the output of this command, too.

Comment: Also , I assumed you've created and attached your public key to your github account. Have you?

Comment: Yes, I have my public key uploaded under SSH Keys section of my github account. In an attempt, I even generated SSH Keys without passphrase and uploaded to github account. But the git push hangs.

Comment: Have you uploaded the Jenkins user's public key?  That would be more important than your own public key, since it's Jenkins that's attempting the git push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21568234/2748399, always check the jenkins logs for more detailed error. Thanks Elizabeth (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2997040/elizabetht) for mentioning me in the post!

Answer (score 7):

I followed the workaround, found by @Saravana Kumar Periyasamy given under the topic 'Possible issues between Jenkins and Github' from the link https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin

Forced the Jenkins to run as the user that has the SSH key configured, uploaded the SSH Key generated without passphrase  and viola, I made my successful Maven Release using Jenkins (After 116 attempts in figuring out the correct configuration with this Jenkins job!!)

Here is the output from the console

```
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git commit --verbose -F C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-170370981.commit pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git symbolic-ref HEAD"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push git@github.com:elizabetht/StudentEnrollmentWithREST.git master:master"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Tagging release with the label StudentEnrollmentWithREST-1.3...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git tag -F C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-1647501295.commit StudentEnrollmentWithREST-1.3"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push git@github.com:elizabetht/StudentEnrollmentWithREST.git StudentEnrollmentWithREST-1.3"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git ls-files"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Transforming 'StudentEnrollmentWithREST'...
[INFO] Not removing release POMs
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git commit --verbose -F C:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-890096458.commit pom.xml"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git symbolic-ref HEAD"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push git@github.com:elizabetht/StudentEnrollmentWithREST.git master:master"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Upload REST Release Artifacts
[INFO] Release preparation complete.
```

And then the job proceeded to upload my artifacts to my release repository.

The  elements in pom.xml are as follows (this worked)

```
<scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:user/repo-name.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:user/repo-name.git</developerConnection>
        <url>git@github.com:user/repo-name.git</url>            
      <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>
```

In my Jenkins job configuration, I specified the Repository URL in the following format

```
git@github.com:user/repo-name.git
```

instead of using https://github.com/user/reponame.git

The entire steps I followed to get the maven release working through Jenkins is available under http://elizabetht.github.io/blog/2014/02/05/jenkins-release-upload/